# Grouping counts

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case, window-functions

I have the below table:

```
NO  ACTION_DT              REQUEST_TYPE STATUS_CD   
3   5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM    CREATE      APPROVED    
3   1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM    UPDATE      APPROVED    
3   4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM    UPDATE      APPROVED    
3   8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM     UPDATE      PENDING 
3   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM     UPDATE      APPROVED    
3   11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM   UPDATE      NEW 
3   11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM   UPDATE      APPROVED    
3   7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM    UPDATE      NEW 
3   7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM    UPDATE      PENDING 
3   7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM    UPDATE      NEW 
3   7/16/2019 2:31:20 PM    UPDATE      PENDING 
3   7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM    UPDATE      APPROVED
```

My Results:

```
    NO      ACTION_DT             REQUEST_TYPE  STATUS_CD REQUEST_START_DT      REQUEST_END_DT        REQUEST RNK_GRP_REQUEST
    803     5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  CREATE        APPROVED  5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  1       1
    803     1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  UPDATE        APPROVED  1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  2       1
    803     4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  UPDATE        APPROVED  4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  3       1
    803     8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   UPDATE        PENDING   8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   4       1
    803     8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   UPDATE        APPROVED  8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   4       2
    803     11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM UPDATE        NEW       11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM 5       1
    803     11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM UPDATE        APPROVED  11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM 5       2
    803     7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  UPDATE        NEW       7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  6       1
    803     7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  UPDATE        PENDING   7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  6       2
    803     7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  UPDATE        NEW       7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  6       3
    803     7/16/2019 2:31:20 PM  UPDATE        PENDING   7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  6       4
    803     7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  UPDATE        APPROVED  7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  6       5
```

The problem I'm running into is request #6. The users don't always follow the process, so there's not an "Approved" or "Denied" before a new request. So, the data should show 7 request. The last three rows are the 7th request.

How can I account for this in my code?

I've tried an `or` statement in my `case expression` but I'm receiving `window function not allowed here`; also NOT sure if that would give me my correct results anyway.

SQL:

```
SELECT 
W.NO,
W.ACTION_DT,
W.REQUEST_TYPE,
W.STATUS_CD,
MIN(W.ACTION_DT ) OVER ( PARTITION BY NO, GRP ) AS REQUEST_START_DT,
MAX(ACTION_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY NO,GRP) AS REQUEST_END_DT,
W.GRP AS REQUEST,
RNK_GRP_REQUEST 
FROM (
   SELECT W.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO,GRP ORDER BY ACTION_DT,STATUS_CD) RNK_GRP_REQUEST      
   FROM ( SELECT 
          W.NO,
          W.ACTION_DT,
          W.REQUEST_TYPE,
          W.STATUS_CD,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ('APPROVED','DENIED') 
          --OR (STATUS_CD IN ('NEW') AND LAG(STATUS_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ACTION_DT, STATUS_CD) NOT IN ('APPROVED','DENIED'))
               THEN 1 END )                                                 
               OVER (PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ACTION_DT)               
               --+ CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ('NEW') AND LAG(STATUS_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ACTION_DT, STATUS_CD) NOT IN ('APPROVED','DENIED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               + CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ('APPROVED','DENIED') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

               AS GRP
          FROM  W
          WHERE 1=1
          AND W.ACTION_DT IS NOT NULL
          )W)W

ORDER BY NO, W.ACTION_DT, REQUEST, RNK_GRP_REQUEST
```

Comment: Business rules to be implemented are not clear to me. What is the condition which starts a brand new request? `new, new, pending, approved,  pending, approved` -  how do you know which one was approved first?

Answer (score 0):

One could use a `CTE` to create the `lag` and then use the lag column in your `case expression` to capture the previous value.

Something like...

```
with prev as (select lag(status_cd) over partition by no order by action_dt, status_cd) as prev_status_cd, no, action_dt, W.NO|| TO_CHAR(W.ACTION_DT,'YYYYMMDD') || W.STATUS_CD AS PK
from w
select 
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ('APPROVED','DENIED') 
      OR W.STATUS_CD IN ('NEW')AND PREV.PREV_STATUS_CD NOT IN ('APPROVED','DENIED')
           THEN 1 END )                                                 
           OVER (PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ACTION_DT)               
           + CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ('APPROVED','DENIED') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
from w
join prev ON W.NO|| TO_CHAR(W.ACTION_DT,'YYYYMMDD') || W.STATUS_CD = PREV.PK
```